# How to get width form keen-slider/react

Tags: reactjs, next.js, frontend

I need to know the width of each slide in the carousel to make the height the same. That way every element of the slider will be square.

[image]

I tried to find information in the [documentation.](https://keen-slider.io/docs) I didn't find anything I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this solution

```
const [ref, internalSlider] = useKeenSlider({...})
const slideHeight = internalSlider.current?.slides?.[0]?.clientWidth;

<div ref={ref} className="keen-slider">
      {slides.map(slide => (
        <div style={{ height: slideHeight }}/>
      )}
</div>
```